# What is the difference between dynamical and non-dynamical correlation and which one is accounted for in Hartree-Fock theory?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

It is my understanding that dynamical is related to the movement of individual electrons. I don't fully understand what this means though.

Non-dynamical correlation is still very unclear from my notes and how it relates to HF theory is very confusing. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50804/41556

Comment: @Harley, this is a good question, you might find it useful to support the proposal for a Stack Exchange dedicated specifically to the "expert-level" modeling side of things: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=Y2JlNjkxZWYyMWEyNzdkZmMzM2UwMWIwMzhlYTIwMTI1OGMzNWY4ZTVjMTAyZDU3MWFkNjEwZjIzMzgxZDVhZdnlQ-Z1y5YVnxsjGvH9jFkvFuyZGzROg66XTw-wSrQL0